# Unable to render component with updated value of constant using async function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, axios

I want to render components based on whether the route passed is in the permissions of a user
but the value of permissions is getting called before it is updated

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import configService from "../_configService";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function render(c: JSX.Element) {
  return c;
}

const ProtectedRoute = (Component: any, route: string) => {
  const currentUser: any = useSelector((state) => state);
  const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = new configService();
    config.loadConfigData().then(() => {
      setPermissions(config.Permissions);
    });
  }, []);

  return currentUser && permissions.includes(route)
    ? render(Component)
    : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use **.then** here so maybe it takes some time for that to complete you can try this in this way by adding loader :

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import configService from "../_configService";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function render(c: JSX.Element) {
  return c;
}

const ProtectedRoute = (Component: any, route: string) => {
  const currentUser: any = useSelector((state) => state);
  const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true); // creating loader state initially it is true

  useEffect(() => {
    const config = new configService();
    config.loadConfigData().then(() => {
      setPermissions(config.Permissions);
      setIsLoading(false); // when this is processed we will set it false

    });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return currentUser && permissions.includes(route)
    ? render(Component)
    : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Explanation :** Initially you will see a div with Loading ...  when the processing in useeffect completed then depending on condition it will go to either '/'route or code in render .

Hope this help.